# Return most recent document in a group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a lot of documents stored in a mongodb collection (> 1M). Each document has a timestamp and they're categorized into a bunch of categories (symbols). How can I get the most recent document (per timestamp) in each category? Keep in mind that this query should be as efficient as possible due to the large number of documents.

My initial approach was to sort the whole collection and then to somehow select the documents using `distinct`. After some reading in the mongodb manual, I realized an aggregation query would best fit my needs.
This is what I have right now:

```
db.trades.aggregate([{$group: {_id: '$symbol', time: {$max: '$time'}}}])
```

This doesn't appear to be correct also is this the correct approach for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Can u provide some examples for Documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator. Something like

```
db.trades.aggregate([
    {$sort: {time: -1}},
    {$group: {_id: '$symbol', doc: {$first: '$$ROOT'}}}
])
```

You need to create an index to ensure the best performance:

```
db.trades.createIndex( { time: -1 } )
```

Comment: Won't this sort the whole collection every time? Is there no way around that?

Comment: $sort is the first stage, so it can benefit from the index. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I already have that. I was thinking maybe grouping before the sort or something. Your solution works but it takes ~4 seconds even with an index.

Comment: I think you need a compound index then. `db.trades.createIndex({symbol: 1, time: -1})`

Comment: Only first stage can use indexes and only for sort or match https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes